# Spring mvc @pathvariable sql injection

Tags: security, spring-mvc

Is using @PathVariable for string variable in controller safe from SQL injection attempt ?

```
@PathVariable("testparameter") String inputtext
```

Comment: That depends on how you construct your SQL query and not on the fact that you use `@PathVariable`. If you do string concatenation to create a SQL then you are vulnerable regardless of the `@PathVariable` or other means of retrieving parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not safe. The PathVariable annotation is just a utility to grab a token out of the URL path in a request.  In most cases this is no safer than taking a parameter from a get or post request.

Use parameterization to build your SQL queries.  That is to say, prepared statements.